# Sideffects when changind some elements of nn.Parameter

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to have some `nn.Parameter` that depend on data, e.g. different values for different people. I realized while training one person, the results of the other people also change. I created a small demo below.

I tried to make everything deterministic and as expected, changing the size of `nn.Parameter` does not change the results. After training for 100 epochs, I always get `[1.0605, 1.0715, 1.0622, 0.9702]` for `all_calibration_params[0]`. But all other parameters of `all_calibration_params` also change, and they all change by the same value, with `all_calibration_params = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(10, 4))` I get `[0.8455, 0.8455, 0.8455, 0.8455]` for all 9 other values. I would expect these values to stay `[1, 1, 1, 1]`. Can anyone please explain to me, why the other values change even though I do not use them during training?

Thank you.

```
import torch
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, Trainer, seed_everything
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F


class DemoDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Generate random data, only for person 0.
    Data is always random but output is always 1.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 1_000

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {
            'person': torch.zeros(1),
            'data': torch.rand(1),
            'output': torch.ones(1),
        }


class DemoModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.all_calibration_params = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(3, 4))  # all values are 1

        self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(1, 4)
        self.fc_2 = nn.Linear(4 + 4, 1)

    def forward(self, person: torch.Tensor, data: torch.Tensor):
        x = self.fc_1(data)
        calibration_params = self.all_calibration_params[person].squeeze(1)
        x = torch.cat((x, calibration_params), dim=1)
        x = self.fc_2(x)

        return x


class Model(DemoModel):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate: float, weight_decay: float, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate, weight_decay=self.weight_decay)

    def training_step(self, train_batch: dict, batch_idx: int):
        data, person, output = train_batch['data'], train_batch['person'].long(), train_batch['output']

        pred = self(person, data)

        loss = F.mse_loss(pred, output)
        return loss


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seed_everything(42)

    model = Model(learning_rate=1e-4, weight_decay=1e-5)

    dataset = DemoDataset()
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64)

    print(model.all_calibration_params)

    trainer = Trainer(
        max_epochs=100,
        deterministic=True
    )
    trainer.fit(model, dataloader)

    print(model.all_calibration_params)

    # model.all_calibration_params[1] should be [1, 1, 1, 1]
    print(model.all_calibration_params[1], torch.ones(1, 4))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1.0605, 1.0715, 1.0622, 0.9702],
        [0.8455, 0.8455, 0.8455, 0.8455],
        [0.8455, 0.8455, 0.8455, 0.8455]], requires_grad=True)
```

EDIT:

I added a small test if the other elements in `nn.Parameter` change the output, but the do not, so I do not understand why they are affected while training.

```
batch = next(iter(dataloader))
data, person = batch['data'], batch['person'].long()
output_org = model(person, data)
print(output_org[0])

model.freeze()
model.all_calibration_params[1:] = torch.ones(2, 4)
model.unfreeze()

output_mod = model(person, data)
print(output_mod[0])
print(torch.equal(output_org, output_mod))
```

Output:

```
tensor([0.6334], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
tensor([0.6334], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset always returns a `0` index for the `'person'`, *i.e.* `self.all_calibration_params[person]` will always select the first rows.

The reason the other two rows are getting updated is because of the weight decay that was set on the optimizer. This will update all parameters regardless of whether they were used or not during the model inference.

Comment: Yes, in this minimal example I want all my data to be of the same person, so only the first row of `self.all_calibration_params` should be changed. My question is, why do the `0.8455` values not stay at `1.`. From my understanding they should not change when the first row is changed.

Comment: I think this has something to do with your weight decay which will affect all parameters regardless of whether they have been used or not during inference.